# GCP's Load Balancing does not distribute in balance to the backend

Tags: google-cloud-platform, load-balancing

GCP's Load Balancing does not distribute in balance to the backend

When specifying backend services in GPC's Load Balancing, multiple backends are specified.
I am using HTTP Load Balancing.

However, multiple backends are not distributed equally.
In fact, when HTTP requests are actually made, they are clearly leaning toward one of the backends.
Is this due to the fact that I am specifying multiple backends?
How can I distribute them evenly?

---

Also describe the specifics of what you are trying to achieve.
The backend is used for machine learning inference, and each request takes about 15 seconds.
Therefore, the QPS (RPS) is set very small. However, it is ignored.

[Basic settings](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8Stuu.png)

[First and second backend settings](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Tjz2F.png)

[Locality load balancing policy settings](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YXz4W.png)

---

Load Balancer

- Global external Application Load Balancer

First backend

- Instance Group
- region: us-west3 (Standard)

Second backend

- Instance group
- region: us-east1 (Preemptible)

Comment: Are the backend in the same region? What's your global architecture?

Comment: Thank you very much.
Not in the same region.
However, it is set to global external application load balancer.

I thought that if multiple backends are specified, they would be equally distributed, but am I understanding this incorrectly?
Currently, for some reason, more requests are being made to the first backend.

I have also set the Locality load balancing policy to round robin.

Added to the original question a description of the status of the load balancer and each backend.

Comment: where are the requests coming from (region)?

Comment: The HTTP load balancer route the request to the closest region from the originator. Your target region backend and the source (asked by John) are important to understand the Load Balancer choices!

Comment: Thank you very much!
The request originates from Cloud Functions and the region is us-central1.
Does this mean that there is a bias towards us-west3?
How can I distribute the request evenly (like round robin) to multiple region backends?

Comment: Perhaps there is no way to evenly distribute the load balancer for multiple regions?